# match any utf8 non-whitespace chars in java?

Tags: java, regex, utf-8

I have been spending hours searching and trying. None of them works. Need to create a regex pattern that would allow

'漢   字'

't \ n'

'  some char'

but not allow

```
"       "

''
```

the pattern I used here

```
Pattern.compile("[\\u0080-\\u9fff]+");
```

is doing a full string match, while I only want part of string to match :(

Thank you for any hints/clues

Comment: Are you using it with `matches()`? Use `Matcher#find()`

Comment: I am actually using the ptn string inside   javax.validation.constraints.Pattern. It seems to me is doing a full string match :(

Comment: Ok, so, why not use `"(?s)\\s*\\S.*"`? This will require at least one non-whitespace char in a string. If you do not expect any line breaks, omit `(?s)`.

Comment: You say `utf8`. That is a 1 to 6/8 code sequence called byte codes, that together comprise the character unit. When you set the _Unicode_ flag in Java, I think it just turns on/off extended ranges for the built in constructs like `\S,\w, etc ..), but has no effect on the internal representation of the character unit. What problem are you having?

Comment: Here is a fiddle link http://fiddle.re/nza9hn

Answer (score 1):

To match a string with at least one non-whitespace char (in the `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern` that requires a full string match, i.e. is anchored by default) use

```
"(?s)\\s*\\S.*"
```

See a [demo of how this regex works](https://regex101.com/r/UEEdgO/2).

The fact that the method that accepts the pattern anchors it by default allows omitting the `^` and `$` anchors here (they are present in the regex demo).

If you do not expect any line breaks in the input, omit `(?s)` (a `Pattern.DOTALL` "embedded flag option", or, in other sources, an inline modifier (option)) from the pattern.

Comment: thank you so much! this works like a charm! But I am not sure I understand this, does \\S include utf-8 chars? however, it does not pass '漢\\字', which I think should certainly qualify :(

Comment: Ok, try with the `(?U)` modifier, like `"(?sU)\\s*\\S.*"`. Or just `"(?s).*\\S.*"`

Comment: does it work for you? not for me when passing ''漢 字''

Comment: [`漢`](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E6%BC%A2%5C%E5%AD%97#title) is a CJK ideograph and is matched with `\S`. You may even use http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/ to test Java regex online. My regex matches the string you provided.

Comment: You may try another regex with a lookahead: `"(?U)(?!\\s*$)[\\s\\S]+"`

Comment: @gigi2: The `\\s*\\S.*` really must work, because `\s` is any whitespace and `\S` is any non-whitespace. They are mutually exclusive, thus, there can be 0+ whitespaces and at least 1 non-whitespace. No options are really required. Unless there is some peculiarity like in Visual Studio where you need to define `\s` as `[\s\r]`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `String.contains()` in this case?

Comment: I am actually using java validation API, javax.validation.constraints.*

Answer (score 0):

Not whitespace `\S+` is this:  (demo   http://fiddle.re/nza9hn )

```
"[^\\u0009-\\u000D\\u0020\\u0085\\u00A0\\u1680\\u2000-\\u200A\\u2028-\\u2029\\u202F\\u205F\\u3000]+"
```

Comment: it does not pass my "key \\ 汉字" input. Here is my pattern validation, @Pattern(regexp="[^\\u0009-\\u000D\\u0020\\u0085\\u00A0\\u1680\\u2000-\\u200A\\u2028-\\u2029\\u202F\\u205F\\u3000]+",
            message = "cannot be empty",
            flags = {Pattern.Flag.UNICODE_CASE})

Comment: @gigi2 - I get no problems using tester http://fiddle.re/nza9hn Press the Java button when the page opens. But, I believe SO inserted some markup inside my text above. Use the link to get the regex. You'll notice there are no regex flags set either.